# Python: how to search within a homogenous values dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
dict = {'a': [1, 'Hello', 3], 'b': {1, 2, 90}, 'c': (1, 2, 'tuple'), 'd': 3}
```

I tried to print each key contains the value 3. The output has to be `a` and `d`

I tired something like this:

```
[key for key, vals in dict.items() if 3 in vals]
```

but an error: int is not iterable 
I also tried to use for :

```
>>> for i in dict.values():
...     if 3 in dict.values():
...             print(i)
```

I also tried this but nothing works

```
>>> for i in dict.keys():
...     if 3 in dict[i]:
...             print(i)
```

PART 2: Let us say I am able to print the key if the value contains 3, then how can I get the index if the value is list or tuple?

Comment: Yeah, so fundamentally you should take care when creating a data-structure. Your values seem to be able to contain any arbitrary value, and if that is the case, you have to specifically deal with this...

Comment: You have a set in there. So getting an index for the search value is not always possible.

Comment: Simple solution: `[key for key, vals in dict.items() if 3 == vals or 3 in vals]` . But this might not work for all the cases you're looking for.

Comment: The problem is that the value for `'d'` does not *contain* 3, it *equals* 3.  If you only want values that *contain* 3, then `3` is not such a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[key for key, vals in dict.items() if 3==vals or 3 in vals]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is because not all your values are of the same type.
Your evaluation needs to be if key equals to 3 then return true, or if the value is a container, check if 3 is part of it.

To get an index of a value in a list OR a tuple, you can use

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 'just', 3, 'p']
>>> l.index(3)
3

>>> t = (1, 2, 'word', 3)
>>> t.index(3)
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for k, v in dict.items():
    try:
        if 3 in v:
            print(k)
    except TypeError:
        if v == 3:
            print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to test if the value of the key is not scalar, before trying to use `in`:

```
def in_key(value, vals):
    if isinstance(vals, (list, tuple, set)):
        return value in vals
    else:
        return value == vals

lst = [key for key, vals in dict.items() if in_vals(3, vals)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost right, just check the item equal or contained in a set of vals:

```
dict = {'a': [1, 'Hello', 3], 'b': {1, 2, 90}, 'c': (1, 2, 'tuple'), 'd': 3}

print [key for key, vals in dict.items() if 3 == vals or 3 in vals]
['a', 'd']
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/K8VC/0)

Comment: No need to convert to a set.  Just do `3 in vals`.

Comment: @BrenBarn I know but for larger data the lookup will be quicker. But in this case you are right, since the data will be lookup only once. Thanks!

Comment: The *lookup* will be quicker, but the overall operation will be slower, because you have to create the set before you can do the lookup.  It might be quicker to store the data as a set in the first place, but that would have different semantics and doesn't match the sample data in the question.

Comment: @BrenBarn, Thats why I said you were right here, cant argue against my words haha ;)